# manually test azure-cosmos sdk exceptions in python

Tags: python

How do I force test exceptions in this below code. In the below code I am creating a record inside of Azure cosmos db and I want to manually test all types of failure scenarios?

```
def resolve_createUser(_, info, user):
    print(user)
    try:
        result = container.create_item({
            "id": user["userDisplayName"]+"-"+user["userPhoneNumber"],
            "partitionKey": "user",
            "userPhoneNumber": user["userPhoneNumber"],
            "userDisplayName": user["userDisplayName"]
        })

    except AzureMissingResourceHttpError as e:
        if e.status_code == 200:
            return {
                "status": e.status_code,
                "error": "",
                "user": result
            }
        else:
            return {
                "status": e.status_code,
                "error": e.message,
                "user": None
            }
    else:
        return {
            "status": 200,
            "error": "",
            "user": result
        }
```